# Error Share facebook android sdk video

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm trying to share a video obtained facebook download directory phone with the following code :

```
Uri selectedVideo = Uri.parse(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/video_name.mp4");
                                 ShareVideo shareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder().setLocalUrl(selectedVideo).build();
                                    ShareVideoContent shareVideoContent = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                                            .setVideo(shareVideo)
                                            .setContentTitle("Video Title")
                                            .setContentDescription("Video description")
                                            .build();

                                    ShareDialog dialog = new ShareDialog(this);
                                    dialog.show(shareVideoContent);
```

Now I have the problem that makes no action when press the button ... I did a test by sending a link in the same function and if I worked. But here it is not doing me any action nor throws an error